# Mixed authentication modes (anonymous and windows) in MVC web app

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, authentication

I've already tried [Use Anonymous authentication in MVC4 on single controller when the whole application uses Windows Authenticaion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15087755/use-anonymous-authentication-in-mvc4-on-single-controller-when-the-whole-applica) and [IIS Mixed Anonymous and Windows Authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34963618/iis-mixed-anonymous-and-windows-authentication) , no such luck so far getting what I need to happen.

We have an MVC app on our network.  Internally, it should use windows authentication, and we use an `[AuthorizeByRole(param[] Role roles)]` Attribute on many of our views / controllers.

However, we also need for external users to be able to access the app.  We have contractors and physicians that don't have AD credentials, plus the mobile app uses an anonymous backend API.

What I need to happen:
Internal users: auto login using windows authentication, nice and simple
External users: Challenge for windows credentials (which it does) - if they hit cancel, they become an anonymous user, and can still view the app.

What happens now:  Hitting cancel causes them to be redirected to the standard asp.net 401 page, rather than seeing the Guest page.  Also, the mobile backend just automatically gets a 401, and can't hit the API at all.

Any thoughts?

#### more information

[Here is a sample solution I have](http://www.fast-files.com/getfile.aspx?file=188157)

In my web.config, I have:

```xml
    <authentication mode="Windows" />
    <authorization>
      <deny users="?" />
      <allow users="*" />
    </authorization>
```

In IIS, I have
[image: authentication settings]

In my API controller, I put `[AllowAnonymous]` on both the controller and my `GetKey` method
On my phone, I go to /api/Auth/GetKey, and I'm challenged for AD credentials.  When I hit cancel, I'm redirected to a 401 page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the Controller is decorated with an `[Authorize]` Attribute, you can exclude individual methods, within that Controller, from the Authorization by decorating them with the `[AllowAnonymous]` Attribute.

Read more about it [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/rickandy/2012/03/23/securing-your-asp-net-mvc-4-app-and-the-new-allowanonymous-attribute/).

On the other hand, you could also remove the `[Authorize]` Attribute from the Controller and only mark methods that need Authorization with it.

Comment: Please see my update.  I tried various things, nothing seems to work yet

Comment: @Para try commenting out the `<authorization>` part in your web.config. The Authenticated should work as expected (as long as the controllers and methods are marked with their respective `Authorize` or `AllowAnonymous` attribute).

Comment: Tried this.  Double checked [Authorize] was on controllers / methods - now all users, even internal, are anonymous :/

Comment: @Para this doesn't seem quite right. Could you maybe post one of your Controllers where this happens. You can leave out the method body and anything business related. Mainly the attributes are important.

Comment: Ok, it's a step closer....  I missed something in our Authorize attribute override we use.  Next problem though - when hitting the site externally, I'm not being challenged for credentials, just being passed to the site as anonymous / guest

Comment: @Para correct me if I'm wrong, but I thought you shouldn't be able to authenticate against the Intra-Net Active Directory via IIS Windows Authentication. If I'm correct, why should an external user be prompted for their Windows credentials. Just to clear up some confusion (mainly on my part).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188439/discussion-between-para-and-tobias-tengler).

Answer (score 0):

You have to decorate controller actions individually instead of the entire controller. Use [Authorize] for actions that only AD users can perform and leave the others undecorated for anonymous users.