# Site with both Window and Anonymous authentication on IIS

Tags: asp.net, web, iis, hosting

I want to host an application on IIS with both windows and anonymous modes. I know it is not possible to run website with both modes on as when I enable anonymous mode, window authentication do not work. What are other alternates by which I can run application in both modes with preference to windows.

P.S I can run two websites but their physical path should be same. Also the original website has binding to server default address, any virtual directory converted to default application by default ask for window authentication. e.g.

172.16.128.190;www.xYZ.com binds to path E:/applications/XYZ

172.16.128.190/MS in default application is mapped to E:applications/MS

Now if I disable window authentication on later application it by default picks authentication from first application (inheritance)

In other scenario I can make another site but same physical path

172.16.128.190;www.xYZ.com binds to path E:/applications/XYZ (Window)

www.xYZipad.com binds to path E:/applications/XYZ (Anonymous)

Please provide possible solutions.

Comment: When you find a need like that, you should review why you cannot avoid it. What's wrong with a site fully protected by Windows authentication?

Comment: Hi Lex, I need website to work on Ipad too along with windows.

Comment: Then the common way is to set up two sites (use a mobile dedicated site). All other hacks only increase long term maintenance cost.

Answer (score 0):

it is not possible to enable both authentications for the same site. if you still host the same folder as an application then it is also not possible because that folder uses the same web.config file.

Your best option is to create a folder where all your secured stuff goes and enable windows authentication on that folder. Keep your public bits in other folders and the root.

You could refer below link:

[IIS Mixed Anonymous and Windows Authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34963618/iis-mixed-anonymous-and-windows-authentication)

Comment: Hi Jalpa, I need exact website for both windows and anonymous settings. I need to make website work on PC and IPad both.